# How to route from a area to the default route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-routing

I have a front page and a CMS area with the following routes:

**Default Front Page route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "SiteFactory.Site.Controllers" }
```

**Administration route**

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Administration_default",
        "administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I would like to route from my ContentController (inside the administration area) to the front page HomeController, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Save(string content, string contentId, string pageId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TODO: save content.
    }
    return RedirectToRoute("Default");
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `return RidirectToAction("Index", "Home");`